# Big loop crashes in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, crash

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

I am updating a word list (2) with the frequency ranking of another list (1). The code is designed to for every entry in list 1 go through list 2 and add the frequency ranking to every identical entry in it. If I limit the list to a few entries in each, it works exactly as intended, but the lists are quite large. List 1 contains 55.000 words and list 2 contains 18.000 words. Is there a way to prevent the code from crashing, or alternatively rewrite it in a more efficient manner? I am sure it is far from optimal, as I am a complete neophyte in VBA. I’ll paste in the code below.

Thanks much

```
Option Explicit
Sub CorrectFrequencyData()

Dim Frequency As Double
Dim CurrentLocation As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set CurrentLocation = Range("i5")

Do Until CurrentLocation.Value = ""

    Frequency = CurrentLocation.Offset(0, -6).Value
    Range("n4").Activate
    
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    
        If ActiveCell.Value = CurrentLocation.Value Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value + Frequency
    
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    
    Loop
    
    Set CurrentLocation = CurrentLocation.Offset(1, 0)
    
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You could just loop the range, save the activates.  So for i=1 to usedrange.rows.count:if range("n" & i).value = currentlocation.value ..... etc.  Use & for concatenation, if the + is to do concatenation, you could also set the calc to be manual

Comment: Why not just use countif() ?? Or if I'm misunderstanding the frequency list and it's already summarised, a sumif() or even a vlookup?()

Comment: @Nathan_Sav The + is to add the numbers together. As I said, the code is doing what it is supposed to do. But probably very inefficiently. I have now got it to work by inserting a DoEvents in the loop. But, as I probably should have expected given the monstrous size of the lists, if it keeps the pace up, it will take approximately 44 days!

Comment: I will explain the situation a little more thoroughly:

Comment: List 1 is a list of words with a number of duplicates—as a result of that I have converted all inflected words into an infinitive form—and is accompanied by a column that contains the frequency of the words in the text. List 2 has had all duplicates removed but it has no frequency information. So what I need to do is combine the frequency information for all the identical entries in list 1 and transfer the sum to the singular entry in list 2.

Comment: Now, as I said, I am very new to VBA, and programming in general for that matter, so I would really appreciate concrete code changes I can make. 

Thanks much

Comment: Do you have example data/layout that you could provide?

Comment: @Zaider You mean like a screen shot of the lists right? I’ll put that up.

Comment: By the way, now that I think about it, if there is a way to simply combine identical entries in the word column and summing up the frequency number accompanying them in the frequency column, that would probably work just as well. I’m not sure whether it is something like that GavinP had in mind. I have to look into the suggested functions.

Comment: Another alternative would be to pivot the data. Without seeing exactly what you're doing and why it's sometimes difficult to offer the best alternative.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the comments! It really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Looks like there may be a few ways to speed up your code.  Firstly you could use a `SUMIF` as GavinP suggested like so in your second frequency column `=SUMIF(I:I, N4, C:C)` If you flow this down for your second frequency column what this is saying is check column I for the value in N + row and everywhere that you find that value at the frequency from column C to a Total.

Now options to speed up your code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CorrectFrequencyData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

I'm not sure if you have formulas in your code but you can set them to manual instead of having them recalculate every time you change values on your sheet.

```
Application.Calculation = -4135 'xlCalculationManual
```

Instead of looping through your sheet you can assign your range to an array and loop through that which is faster.  We can also eliminate the need to loop through the second list for every entry in the first list.  We'll do this by storing the first list of words and their frequency in a dictionary

```
Dim ArrWords() as variant
Dim LastRow as long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 9).End(-4162).Row  'Version non-specific Endrow, xlUP
ArrWords = Range("C4:I" & LastRow)

Dim dicWordFrequency as Object
Set dicWordFrequency = CreateObject("Dictionary.Scripting")

Dim tempWord as String

Dim i as Long
For i = 1 to Ubound(ArrWords)
    tempWord = arrWords(i,7)
    If not dicWordFrequency.Exists(tempWord) then
       DicWordFrequency.Add tempWord, arrWords(i,1)
    Else
       DicWordFrequency.Item(tempWord)= dicWordFrequency.Item(tempWord) + arrWords(i,1)
    End If
Next
```

Now we can loop through your worksheet and update the frequencies for the words in the second list.

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 14).End(-4162).Row  'Version non-specific Endrow, xlUP
ArrWords = Range("N4:O" & LastRow)
For i = 1 to Ubound(arrWords)
    tempWord = arrwords(i,1)
    If dicWordFrequency.Exists(tempWord) then
        arrWords(i,2) = dicWordFrequency.Item(tempWord)
    End If
Next        

'Dump your new array with the totals to a range
Dim result as Range
Set Result = Range("N4")
Result.ReSize(UBound(arrWords,1), Ubound(ArrWords,2)).value = arrWords

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = -4105  'xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried the sumif function as suggested, but I’m not quite sure it adds up correctly. I will have to check a few more numbers.